# Batch Script that check if a network drive exists, if does, do nothing, if doesnt - map the path

Tags: batch-file, mapping, drive

I'm trying to create a mapping script that mapping a network drive
and I want to add a checking if the drive letter exist, then Do nothing
just show 'Drive is in use'
and if not exist, map it.

this is what i got so far:

```
@echo off
@net use G: /delete /yes
@net use G: \\domainIP\shared folder /user:username password /persistent:yes 

:DONE
:EXIT
@pause
```

please help.

Comment: Why the `typescript` tag? Do you intent to use this language in some way?

Comment: I guess that was tagged by mistake and I didnt noticed.

Comment: I would suggest that the script you've posted will not work! Also, you need to confirm that you're disinterested in whether that  shared folder is mapped as a drive, only if that specific drive letter is in use!

Answer (score 1):

This will check if the **network drive** exist

```
net use | find "G:"
if %errorlevel%==0 goto :exist
@net use G: \\domainIP\shared folder /user:username password /persistent:yes
goto :end
:exist
@echo Drive is in use
:end
```

Answer (score 1):

How about simply using:

```
if exist G:\ (echo Drive is in use) ELSE (net use G: \\domainIP\shared folder /user:username password /persistent:yes)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if not exist r:\ net use r: \\127.0.0.1\C$
```

although if R: is always C$ then there is no need to test. Testing is wrong. It chews battery power, CPU cycles, Hard disk hits, etc.

So

```
net use r: \\127.0.0.1\C$
```

Will map it if it's not already mapped, else it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I have this one ([`VonC/setupsenv`#`installs/drive_detection.bat`](https://github.com/VonC/setupsenv/blob/92cbbcb1a526e539acd0cb465557f2db5b0405ee/installs/drive_detection.bat)), based on the target mapped path.

It looks for the path, check there is a drive, and, if that drive is "Unavailable", it will launch an `explorer.exe` in order to force the drive to be accessed/available again.
There is a [simpler option with Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/sl-SI/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/mapped-network-drive-fail-reconnect).

The reactivation process (where explorer.exe is launched, in order to "refresh" an existing drive displayed as "Unavailable") is:

```bash
:ActivateMappedNetworkDrive
set PROCESSNAME=explorer.exe
set PREFIX=start /min
set SUFFIX=%1

rem echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~azerty
rem First save current pids with the wanted process name
set "RETPIDS="
set "OLDPIDS=p"
for /f "TOKENS=1" %%a in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='%PROCESSNAME%'" get ProcessID ^| findstr [0-9]') do (set "OLDPIDS=!OLDPIDS!%%ap")

rem Spawn new process(es)
%PREFIX% %PROCESSNAME% %SUFFIX%

rem Wait for a second (may be optional)
REM choice /c x /d x /t 1 > nul
C:\Windows\System32\timeout.exe /t 5 > NUL

rem Check and find processes missing in the old pid list
for /f "TOKENS=1" %%a in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='%PROCESSNAME%'" get ProcessID ^| findstr [0-9]') do (
if "!OLDPIDS:p%%ap=zz!"=="%OLDPIDS%" (set "RETPIDS=/PID %%a !RETPIDS!")
)

rem Kill the new threads (but no other)
taskkill %RETPIDS% /T > NUL 2>&1
goto:eof
```